# Picasso causes app to crash saying path is null? Code works in another adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I am trying to display User Profile Image and Username in a User Search view (RecycleView) by calling an adapter - code below.But the same code that works in another Adapter, and on the profile page etc gives a null pointer error and crashes? I cant seem to understand why, since it works in every other place in the app but not in this adapter? Can anybody please help me understand and resolve this issue? The code was working earlier but I then made the switch from CircularImageView to ShapeableImageView

Please note I am using a null check and the path/link to profile is not empty and same works in other palces...

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: in.latom.latom, PID: 19549
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be empty.
        at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.load(Picasso.java:332)
```

Adapter Code

```
class UserAdapter(mContext: Context, mUsers: List<Users>,isChatCheck: Boolean): RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder?>()
{

private val mContext: Context = mContext
private val mUsers:List<Users> = mUsers
private var isChatCheck: Boolean = isChatCheck

override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_search_item_layout,viewGroup,false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return mUsers.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val user: Users? = mUsers[position]
    val firstname = user?.getFirstName()
    val surname = user?.getSurName()
    val username = "$firstname $surname"
    holder.userNameText.text = username
    if(user!!.getProfile() != null) {
        Picasso.get().load(user.getProfile()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_baseline_whatshot_24).fit().centerCrop().into(holder.profileImage)
    }
    //present tagline
        if((user.getRole() != "")) {
            val company = user.getCname()!!
            val tag = user.getRole()!!
            val companyrole = "$tag at $company"
            if (tag.isNotEmpty() && company.isNotEmpty()) {
                holder.tagline.text = companyrole
            } else {
                holder.tagline.text = tag
            }
        } else {
            holder.tagline.visibility = View.GONE
        }

    //Menu on Search Fragment
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val options = arrayOf<CharSequence>(
            "Send Message",
            "Visit Profile"
        )
        val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        builder.setTitle("What would you like to do?")
        builder.setItems(options, DialogInterface.OnClickListener {_, which ->
            if(which == 0)
            {
                val intent = Intent(mContext, MessageActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("visit_id", user!!.getUID() )
                mContext.startActivity(intent)
            }
            if(which == 1)
            {
                val intent = Intent(mContext, VisitUserProfile::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("visit_id", user!!.getUID() )
                mContext.startActivity(intent)
            }

        })
        builder.show()
    }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
{
    var userNameText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username)
    var tagline: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tagline_status)
    var profileImage: ShapeableImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)
}
```

}

Update:

I resolved the issue by updating the below ViewHolder line for the image from ShapeAbleImageView to ImageView as defined in the layout. Bad miss on my part!

var profileImage: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image)

Answer (score 0):

the issue was with incorrect widget declaration during findviewbyid, had to do a ImageView but had done a ShapeableImageView

Comment: From Review: Could you please also provide the source code?